# How to pass Data to viewContainerRef Component in Angular?

Tags: angular, components

How can I pass data to a child component when it gets rendered from viewContainerRef? In my case the EventRegistrationComponent has a navbar with taps and I change ng-template component with my render function below. Every component I can switch to need the same event information

EventRegistrationComponent  `<ng-template appEventRegistration></ng-template>`

```
 @ViewChild(EventRegistrationDirective, { static: true }) registrationHost: EventRegistrationDirective;
 otherFunction(){
     this.render(EventRegistrationInfoComponent);
 }

 public render(component): void {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component as any);
    const viewContainerRef = this.registrationHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    const comp = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    comp['event'] = this.event;
 }
```

Directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appEventRegistration]',
})
export class EventRegistrationDirective {
   constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

ChildComponent

```
export class EventRegistrationInfoComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() event: Event;

    ngOnInit(): void {
       console.log('Info Event');
       console.log(this.event); //undefined

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow this Guide: https://medium.com/@davembush/dynamically-add-components-in-angular-7dc62b2a58d3

Component `<ng-template #dynamicInsert></ng-template>`

```
   @ViewChild('dynamicInsert', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicInsert: ViewContainerRef;
   otherFunction(){
      const dyynamicComponent = this.render(EventRegistrationHomeComponent) as EventRegistrationHomeComponent;
      dyynamicComponent.event = this.event;
  }

  render(component: any): any {
    const componentFactory = 
    this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    this.dynamicInsert.clear();
    return this.dynamicInsert.createComponent(componentFactory).instance;
  }
```

no Directive, ChildComponent same as in question